# Strange problem reading binary file data from network

Tags: python, windows, file

I have a very simple python script which reads file data and calculates the number of bytes read.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os

file_path = sys.argv[1]
expected_size = os.stat(file_path).st_size
read_size = 0
with open(file_path, 'rb') as source:
    while True:
        chunk = source.read(1024 ** 2)
        if not chunk:
            break
        read_size += len(chunk)
print(expected_size, read_size)
```

Effectively this script calculates the size of file in bytes using two different methods, and, as strange as it is, the reported numbers are sometimes different.

My colleague (he is using windows with python 3.5 installed) runs this script specifying path to the file on network and gets the following result:

`571013088 571340768`  <- second number is "incorrect" here

If he copies the file from network to local disk, the result is as expected:

`571013088 571013088`

I run the same script on my linux workstation, the result is always correct.

(original script was a little more useful: it copied files from network share displaying progress bar. The result was that copied file is corrupted.)

The same problem happens with many different files (probably with all quite large files).

Any ideas how to investigate what's going on?

Comment: Did you try setting up a script to read a file this way from the network, write the result to local disk from the script, and then use an existing file-comparison tool to see what the differences are?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Probably this will be the next step. So far I only know that the target file is corrupted. Frankly speaking I do not understand yet how the information about what excatly is corrupted will help me :(

Comment: You can't `break` when there is no loop. Did you mean to read `while chunk`?

Comment: With that fix, I can't repro. I'm guessing the problem was that you didn't read the entire file. https://ideone.com/cRaOd7

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for feedback. Probably the problem is very much specific to computer configuration, but I do not understand how that can be. Script is very simple and must read the entire file. Note, that in this case the size of read chunks is even larger than actual file size...

Comment: What is the actual size of the file according to the OS? Do either of the values calculated match that?

Comment: Are you *wrinting* the file somewhere on Windows? What does that code look like?

Comment: @martineau the size reported by `os.stat(file_path).st_size` is always correct

Comment: @tripleee This is just a test script which I wrote to pin the problem. Original script is much longer and it does write chunks to local file. The result is that target file is corrupted. It's size is different from the size of original file and it is the same as the sum of lengths of chunks reported by this test script.

Comment: So can you add a `print` inside the loop to see if it diverges slowly, or suddenly at the end? Maybe use a smaller buffer and smaller test data. My suspicion is still that Windows does some weird stuff if you can't thoroughly convince all involved layers that you are dealing with binary.